# coordinate mapping in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mapping, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I've been working on a physics simulation, and I've been having some trouble with coordinates.

I haven't been able to find how the scenes are mapped, and to what objects are mapped to when I don't use mapToScene();

My Code is as follows:

Ball.cpp

```
Ball::Ball()
{
    //random start angle

    angle = (qrand() % 360);
    setRotation(angle);

    //set the speed
    speed = 5;


    //random start position
    int StartX = 0;
    int StartY = 0;


    if((qrand() % 1))
    {
        StartX = (qrand() % 200);
        StartY = (qrand() % 200);

    }
    else
    {
        StartX = (qrand() % 100);
        StartY = (qrand() % 100);
    }


    setPos(mapToScene(StartX,StartY));
    qDebug() << "xposition:" << pos().x();
    qDebug() << "yposition:" << pos().y();
    qDebug() << "xposition mapped:"  << mapToScene(pos()).x();
    qDebug() << "yposition mapped:" << mapToScene(pos()).y();

}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene (this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene (scene);

    ui->graphicsView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    double sceneULx = -400;
    double sceneULy = 200;
    double scenewidth = 800;
    double sceneheight = 400;

    scene->setSceneRect(sceneULx, sceneULy,scenewidth,sceneheight);

    QPen mypen = QPen(Qt::red);

    QLineF TopLine(scene->sceneRect().topLeft(),scene->sceneRect().topRight());
    QLineF LeftLine(scene->sceneRect().topLeft(),scene->sceneRect().bottomLeft());
    QLineF RightLine(scene->sceneRect().bottomRight(),scene->sceneRect().topRight());
    QLineF BottomLine(scene->sceneRect().bottomLeft(),scene->sceneRect().bottomRight());

    scene->addLine(TopLine,mypen);
    scene->addLine(LeftLine,mypen);
    scene->addLine(RightLine,mypen);
    scene->addLine(BottomLine,mypen);

    int ItemCount = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i <ItemCount; i++)
    {
       Ball *item = new Ball();
       scene->addItem(item);
    }

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()), scene,SLOT(advance()));
    timer->start(10);
}
```

currently all the objects I generate are not in the area of the scene, which doesn't make any sense to me since I thought that the upper left corner of the scene was 0/0 and it went into the positive when you went down or to the right.

also the qDebugs  yield following results:

```
xposition: 25.6601
yposition: 22.306
xposition mapped: 30.392 
yposition mapped: 55.9751 
xposition: -56.6299 
yposition: 79.0004
xposition mapped: -136.607 
yposition mapped: 23.7579 
xposition: 31.6448 
yposition: 32.3822 
xposition mapped: 76.5177 
yposition mapped: 38.4172 
xposition: 50.017 
yposition: -97.4695 
xposition mapped: -59.4804 
yposition mapped: -93.9612 
xposition: -44.0378 
yposition: 9.25605 
xposition mapped: -33.8154 
yposition mapped: -34.5675
```

I can't really find a correlation between the mapped and the unmapped numbers and it is also very strange the the mapped numbers have decimals altough I define them with an int.

I hope somebody can help me clear my confusion with the coordinate system of this programm.

Comment: I suggest you build a very simple scene with convenient metrics, experiment with it until you understand how coordinate mapping works, and then try to use it. Qt is a bit illogical quite often.

Comment: but how is it possible that  mapToScene(pos().x()) returns something different than scenePos().x() they should be the same or is somehting wrong with my basic understanding of this?

Comment: It seems you have an answer to your question. Wanted to add that I made this tutorial on Qt coordinate spaces with small demo code example here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY3WZvE9AV8&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea about the coordinate system, but have confused yourself with an oversight in the code.

When a Ball item is created, in the constructor, it creates random coordinates and then calls this:

```
setPos(mapToScene(StartX,StartY));
```

As the documentation for [mapToScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mapToScene) states: -

> Maps the point *point*, which is in this item's coordinate system, to the scene's coordinate system, and returns the mapped coordinate.

However, the code is executed in the Ball's constructor and has not yet been added to the scene, so it can't successfully map the coordinates as it has no parent item and no scene with which to map to.

You can call setPos in the constructor, but without mapToScene

```
setPos(StartX,StartY);
```

With no parent, when the item is added to the scene, it will match its scene coordinates (item->pos() == item->scenePos())

Alternatively, create a Ball item, add it to the scene, and then set its position.

```
for(int i = 0; i <ItemCount; i++)
{
   Ball *item = new Ball();
   scene->addItem(item);

   // note that mapToScene is irrelevant, since there is no parent item for the Ball.
   item->setPos(x, y); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for an experiment you can do the following trick:

```
//random start position
int StartX = 100;
int StartY = 100;

setPos(mapToScene(StartX,StartY));
qDebug() << "xposition:" << pos().x();
qDebug() << "yposition:" << pos().y();
qDebug() << "xposition mapped:"  << mapToScene(pos()).x();
qDebug() << "yposition mapped:" << mapToScene(pos()).y();
```

You will see that coordinates are still random. Basically, you are randomizing coordinates 3 times and no wonder there is no correlation.

Also try this:

```
double sceneULx = 0;
double sceneULy = 0;
double scenewidth = 800;
double sceneheight = 400;
```